# Optimization problem on stochastic matrices

Tags: optimization, stochastic-matrices

A matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is a *stochastic matrix* if
$A \in [0, 1]^{m \times n}$ and $\sum_j A_{ij} = 1, \forall i \in [n]$.
Let $\mathcal{S_{m, n}}$ be the set of $m \times n$ stochastic matrices.

If we have an optimization problem on $S_{m, n}$:
$$\arg \min_{A \in \mathcal{S_{m,n }}} f(A)$$
with $f: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$,
how can we solve it via, e.g., gradient descent?

A possible way is to use any existing optimization algorithm on $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with a softmax transform on each row to find
$\arg \min_{A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}} f(\operatorname{row-wise-softmax}(A))$.

For doubly stochastic matrices, we have existing methods where the set of all doubly stochastic matrices forms a manifold and we may solve the optimization problem on the manifold.

[1] https://www.manopt.org/manifold_documentation_multinomialdoublystochastic.html

[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02628

Can we have a manifold for stochastic matrices too? Or can we have other methods to solve optimization problems on stochastic matrices?